# Dovecot Mail Killed with Signal 15

Tags: dovecot

My Dovecot always crashes after about half an hour. Error log (`/var/log/mail.log`) says:

```
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap-login: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: message repeated 2 times: [ imap-login: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)]
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: auth-worker(32132): Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=150 out=591
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=889 out=3101
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=9446 out=201067
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=10705 out=1969769
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=10109 out=458737
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=9041 out=154798
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 24 12:05:07 yetzner dovecot: imap: Server shutting down. in=11253 out=462703
```

Before this, my mail server runs well. After this, I have to restart the dovecot service. What is killing dovecot?

Comment: Do you have to restart the whole OS, or just dovecot? ([edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/231812/edit)  your question to clarify)

Comment: Just dovecot. I use service dovecot restart

Comment: Could you name your OS/Distribution?  It seems like something related to service(s) management - OS/Distribution may help to provide more specific help/recipes.

Comment: Im running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: @mari1355 dovecot service killed by pid 1 (init process) 
did you update whole OS or at least dovecot and kernel!?